# How to set Buttons and Buttons Hover to stay inline?

Tags: html, css

have a small Buttons CSS hover, that when i hover with mouse cursor i see the hover moves and change the Buttons inline order.

What i have:

[image]
What i want:
[image]

I try to use `display:inline-block;` but without success.

See snippet below

```css
.btn {
  background-color: #ddd;
  border: none;
  color: black;
  padding: 16px 32px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin: 4px 2px;
  transition: 0.3s;
  cursor:pointer;
  display:inline-block;
}

.btn:hover {
  padding: 30px;
  padding-left: 50px;
  padding-right: 50px;
  background-color: #eb1269;
  color: white;
  display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<h2>Fading Buttons - "Fade in Effect"</h2>

<button class="btn">Hover Over Me</button> 
<button class="btn">Hover Over Me</button>  
<button class="btn">Hover Over Me</button>
```

Comment: don't change the padding. Change height and width of the button or use `transform: scale(1.1)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```css
.btn {
  background-color: #ddd;
  border: none;
  color: black;
  padding: 16px 32px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin: 4px 15px;
  transition: 0.3s;
  cursor:pointer;
  display:inline-block;
}

.btn:hover {
  transform:scale(1.3);
  background-color: #eb1269;
  color: white;
  display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<h2>Fading Buttons - "Fade in Effect"</h2>

<button class="btn">Hover Over Me</button> 
<button class="btn">Hover Over Me</button>  
<button class="btn">Hover Over Me</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can just add `transform: scale(1.3);`  in `.btn:hover` and remove padding

you can also set proper margin like `margin: 4px 8px`  in  `.btn` so it looks properly

Answer (score 0):

Do not change anything just write in the scale

```
  .btn:hover {
      padding: 30px;
      padding-left: 50px;
      padding-right: 50px;
      background-color: #eb1269;
      color: white;
      display:inline-block;
      transform: scale(0.7); /* Equal to scaleX(0.7) scaleY(0.7) */
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Since in your example the text doesn't scale, there is no transition and when hovered a button overlaps the adjacent buttons, you could add a `box-shadow`, playing with `position:relative` and `z-index`

```css
.btn {
  background-color: #ddd;
  border: none;
  color: black;
  padding: 16px 32px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin: 4px 6px;
  cursor:pointer;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  display:inline-block;
}

.btn:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 20px #eb1269;
  background-color: #eb1269;
  z-index: 2;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<h2>Fading Buttons - "Fade in Effect"</h2>

<button class="btn">Hover Over Me</button> 
<button class="btn">Hover Over Me</button>  
<button class="btn">Hover Over Me</button>
```

Answer (score -3):

Added **transform property with scale function**. It is working as you expected.**transform: scale(1.2);**

```css
.btn {
  background-color: #ddd;
  border: none;
  color: black;
  padding: 16px 32px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin: 4px 2px;
  transition: 0.3s;
  cursor:pointer;
  display:inline-block;
}

.btn:hover {
  padding: 30px;
  padding-left: 50px;
  padding-right: 50px;
  background-color: #eb1269;
  color: white;
  display:inline-block;
  **transform: scale(1.2);**  
}
```

```html
<h2>Fading Buttons - "Fade in Effect"</h2>

<button class="btn">Hover Over Me</button> 
<button class="btn">Hover Over Me</button>  
<button class="btn">Hover Over Me</button>
```